# Image upload functionality with preview

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

I have to implement an image upload functionality in asp.net. The method I have followed works like this :-

Submit a form containing an `<input type='file'>` element and set the target of the form to a named iframe[to give the impression of a Ajax request/response ]. The aspx file which this form is posted to, writes the image into the response as `Reponse.Write("<img src='location'/>");` The image displayed is due for cropping (where i plan to use [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)).

What I would like to know is : Is there another way to display the image in a `<div>` may be, rather than in an iframe which I think is far better than this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you have or can get access to the 'location' value you certainly have everything you need to be able to add a div element to your response:

`Response.Write("<div><img src='location'/></div>");`

Or possibly use something like jQuery to simply set the content of an existing div:

```
$("#uploadedImage").html("<img src='location' />");
```

In your HTML document:

```
<div id="uploadedImage"></div>
```

Comment: where will the response be written in this case? in the target of the form being submitted rite.. what will be the target then????

Comment: The target would still be a form, i.e., upload.aspx or possibly even the current page being viewed. To avoid the appearance of a postback you will need to leverage an actual Ajax call.

Comment: is an ajax call possible to upload a file?